# Letting accessible users know that a parent container has a new "current" child

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

We have a web-based application that is basically composed of a bunch of child `<div>` tags (screens) inside of a single parent `<main>` (container). Each child screen has at least one path to another sibling screen but several have multiple paths. Only one screen can ever be active at a time. Visually, screens slides in from the right and exit to the left. All screens not shown have the [`hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) attribute set after their transition completes. A simplified version of the DOM would be:

```
<main>
    <div data-screen-name="Intro"></div>
    <div hidden data-screen-name="Getting started"></div>
    <div hidden data-screen-name="Create an account"></div>
    <div hidden data-screen-name="Learn more about XYZ"></div>
</main>
```

We're using JS to transition/hide things but for the most part there's no AJAX and the DOM lives exactly as the server-provided HTML.

My question is, assuming this setup, what is the best way, if any, to let non-visual users know that `<main>` has new content?

We were looking at [`aria-live`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) along with `aria-atomic="true"` set on `<main>` but aren't sure if that's too disruptive. We are definitely changing something but we think that alerting might be too strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aria-live` is generally used when adding/removing/updating content.  If the parent container had `aria-live`, then if a new child DOM element was added to the parent, it would be announced to screen readers.  If an existing DOM element was updated (for example, if the text changed), it would also be announced.

However, if you are just unhidding an existing DOM element, the act of hiding/unhiding is not announced.

It sounds like you kind of have a singe page app (SPA) or sort of a carousel.

Does the user initiate the change of content?  Do they select a next button?  Does the unhidden content have any focusable elements in it?  One possibility is to set the focus on the heading of the new content.  The heading would need `tabindex="-1"` so that you can call focus() on it.  You don't want a tabindex of 0 because that would allow normal keyboard tabbing to focus on it and you typically don't want to allow focus to move to something that is not interactive.  But programmatically putting the focus on the heading is ok.  The user can then <kbd>tab</kbd> to the next focusable element in the new content.

If you don't put the focus on the heading of the new content, then you could put focus on the first focusable element in the content, but that's not as good of a solution.  The screen reader user would have to figure out their context of this new element and would probably browse the DOM backwards to see where they are.  By programmatically putting the focus on the heading, you've done the work for them.

Comment: Thanks @slugolicious! You are right in that the app is mostly an SPA. Users do have control of the flow with buttons, sometimes next/previous but also sometimes multiple choice. We actually tried calling `focus()` on the active heading but I didn't know about the `tabindex="-1"` part which is probably why it wasn't working. Thanks for the comments on `aria-live`, too, that just felt wrong to use for this.